# Unexpected exception: java.io.IOException: RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for multipart

Tags: curl, apt, nexus3

Using nexus-repository-apt plugin and trying to upload *.deb packages with curl according to this instructions:

```
curl -u user:pass -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --data-binary "@package.deb" http://nexus_url:8081/repository/repo_name/
```

Also tried to upload from API section in the Nexus GUI. Could not make it work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem and [issued](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-apt/issues/112) to the maintainer. It might be a bug of 3.15.2 version of Nexus including Apt repository. After upgrading to 3.16.1 the issue has been wiped out. So, It works fine now.